# How to update a record in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm new to learning Laravel 5. I'm following a tutorial and I have the following code in my controller. What I want is to update the username with `ID=10` in my login database. I follow the tutorial and also the Laravel documentation but what happens is it inserts another record instead of updating the existing. What is wrong with my code?

Routes.php:

```
Route::get('/users', "PagesController@login");
```

login.php (model)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class login extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'login';

    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'password'
    ];    
}
```

PagesController.php

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\login; //added
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

    class PagesController extends Controller
    {
       public function login()
        {
          $login = new login;
          $login::find(10);
          $login->username ='updated_username';
          $login->save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the result of `var_dump($login);` after `$login::find(10);`?

Comment: the result shows the data in ID number 10

Comment: Try same thing in Tinker, its good for debugging just run `php artisan tinker` and then type the code and see the result there itself

Comment: it works now. i just configure my database the ID fields was changes to small letter id and it works. perfectly thank you all!

Answer (score 5):

By creating new `login` object means you are creating new record. Simply use `login::find()` to load your existing record.

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
      $login = login::find(10);
      $login->username ='updated_username';
      $login->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. i tried but nothing happens. but the  return  $login = login::find(10); shows result. its just didnt update.

Answer (score 0):

```
class PagesController extends Controller
    {
       public function login()
        {
          $login = (new App\Login)->find(10);
          $login->username ='updated_username';
          $login->save();
        }
    }
```

Remember that your classname should start with an uppercase letter "use App\Login" and not "use App\login". Optionally you can reference the class directly with "new App\Login".